# Date function format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, date, datetime

i'm passing start date as `7/02/2014` in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, to add one month extra for current passed date, first i need to convert the passed var item to Date format and then i can manipulate on it.

if i try to get date like this,  `var newDate = new Date(startDate.val());` then i will be getting new date as 7 july 2014, i.e format of date i'm getting in response is `mm/dd/yyyy`.

i need output of `date()` to be in `dd/mm/yyyy` format only. how to achieve this?

Is there any other function in jquery to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dateArr = '7/02/2014'.split('/');
var date = new Date();
date.setYear(dateArr[2]);
date.setMonth(dateArr[1] -1); //month starts from 0
date.setDate(dateArr[0]);
```

Comment: What is month starts from 0?, i didnt understand

Comment: this means , that date.setMonth(0) will set month to January , date.setMonth(2) - March etc.

Comment: Oh, i understood +1 for your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use jquery

```
var date = $.format.date(new Date(Date), 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Comment: inner Date is of type string?

Comment: var Date = startDate.val()  ; 
$.format.date(new Date(Date), 'dd/mm/yyyy');

Comment: oh, i think i need to install plugin for this :(, else i get error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: yea required , //code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0):

Actually I recommend jQuery Datepicker. Because really simple and comprehensible.

You dont have any edits because datepicker default options show like this : dd/mm/yyyy

jQuery;

```
 $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 });
```

Html;

```
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Check it : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
var newDate = new Date("2/7/2014");
var dateformat = newDate.getDate();
dateformat+="/";
dateformat+=newDate.getMonth()+1;
dateformat+="/";
dateformat+=newDate.getYear();
alert(dateformat);
```